# Display multiple rows in a textview Android

Tags: android, textview

Hello guys I want to display records. However, I don't want to display them in listview but in textview. I have in my to do the new line feed \n to do the trick, but in my program, it just shows the first record.

This is what I've tried so far:

**MainActivity.class**

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        dog_name = extras.getString("dog_name");
        cursor = dbHelper.fetchbBreedByName(dog_name);

        strID = cursor.getString(0);
        strDesc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description"));
        strDiet = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("diet"));
        strShelter = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("shelter"));
        strHygiene = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("hygiene"));
        strMedication = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("medication"));
        strBreed = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("breed"));

        Log.d("Animal ID", "Animal ID is " + strID + " and breed is " + strBreed);
        Log.d("Desc", "Desc " + strDesc);
        Description.setText(strDesc);
        Diet.setText(strDiet);
        Shelter.setText(strShelter);
        Hygene.setText(strHygiene);
        Medication.setText(strMedication); }
```

**DBHelper.class**

```
        public Cursor fetchbBreedByName(CharSequence inputText) throws SQLException {

      Cursor mCursor = null;
      if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
       mCursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_DESCRIPTION, 
               KEY_DIET, KEY_SHELTER, KEY_HYGIENE, KEY_MEDICATION, KEY_BREED },
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
          String qry = "SELECT _id, description, diet, shelter, hygiene, medication, " +
                "breed FROM tblAnimalInfo WHERE breed LIKE '%" + inputText + "%';";

          mCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(qry, null);
       //mCursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_DESCRIPTION, 
        //     KEY_DIET, KEY_SHELTER, KEY_HYGIENE, KEY_MEDICATION, KEY_BREED },
       //  KEY_BREED + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null, null, null, null);
      }
      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;

}
```

I don't know what's wrong. Please help me figure out what's missing in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are only loading the first row given by your Cursor. You have to use cursor.moveToNext(); to be able to get the rest of your data. Take a look to the example below:

```
// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
        // Adding contact to list
        contactList.add(contact);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return contact list
return contactList;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are missing cursor.moveToNext() function to move to the next record, as mentioned earlier. Besides I would like to mention a few other issues in the coding style. You should not call moveToFirst() in the query function itself, use it where you are actually traversing through the records. Also make sure you close the cursor appropriately. So your code should look like:

```
cursor = dbHelper.fetchbBreedByName(dog_name);
if (cursor != null) {
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
          ....
          < access the record >
          ...       
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }

   cursor.close();  // very important
}
```

And remove these lines from fetchbBreedByName()

```
if (mCursor != null) {
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may I ask what should be placed inside the access record for my app?

Comment: Reading all the fields of the records with cursor.getString(), that you are already doing it.